# how to read values of execution time of mssql?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-execution-plan

Can some please help on how to analyze execution time in SSMS and from client Statistics tab. I'm confused how to decipher the time needed for execution, if its in msec or sec?

**SSMS**: at the below right corner it show 00:00:01 -->is it 1 msec?

**Client Statistics** below shows  the execution time of proc Trail1,Trial2,Trial3 in msec or sec?.

```
-------------------------trial1-----trial2------trial3--------Avg



Client processing time      442 ,       6   ,    702,         383.3333

Total execution time       1204 ,      190    ,   1220  ,     871.3333

Wait time on server replies 762 ,      184  ,     518,        488.0000
```

[image]

```
**set statistics time on**  
     SQL Server Execution Times:
     CPU time = 688 ms,  elapsed time = 974 ms.
```

Comment: *"at the below right corner it show 00:00:01 -->is it 1 msec?!"* No, it's like other clocks and in the format `hh:mm:ss`. If a timer has milliseconds, it is after a period (`.`). Also, you would certainly visually see the timer increasing is the last characters were centiseconds.

Comment: As for the rest of your question, [“Can someone help me?”isn't an actual question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) What do you need help with? What are you trying to achieve? What are the results you are asking? What have you tried to get the results you want?

Comment: I am in doubt how to analyze the execution time in the chart populated in the CLient Statistics tab(as shown in pic).Can you please help on it.Also I did try command 'set statistics time on' and it gave 974 ms .Iam looking out wats in MSSQL to figure out execution time.

Comment: That doesn't answer my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266218/how-to-read-values-of-execution-time-of-mssql?noredirect=1#comment120651327_68266218). Again, what do you need help *with* **specifically**... Read the FAQ I linked to.

Comment: @Larnu:Thank you .... I  got the answer from you ,as you said the format is hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query the first time you will see the SQL Server parse and compile-time and this time informations are related to the query optimizer statistics.

For example, after we enable the **[SET STATISTICS TIME ON](https://www.sqlshack.com/usage-details-of-the-set-statistics-time-on-statement-in-sql-server/)** option we will see the following output:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

[image]

**Parse and Compile-Time**
CPU time indicates the time that how long it takes to parse and compile on CPU. The elapsed time indicates the total time that is spent to parse and compile the query and it also includes the CPU time

**Execution Times**
The second information is related to the query execution times
The CPU time indicates the total time that is spent by the CPU(s)
The elapsed time is the total time to complete the execution of the query.

> **[For the client statistics:](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/12/sql-server-management-studio-include-client-statistics-button/)** The time statistics tells you how much
> time was spent processing on the client versus how much time was spent
> waiting for the server. These figures are in milliseconds.